# Change position of Snackbar while it is shown based on BottomNavigationView's visibility

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-snackbar

I have a BottomNavigationView within a CoordinatorLayout in my activity. I have a Snackbar that is displayed above the BottomNav so all good there. Based on some conditions the BottomNav visibility is modified. However the snackbar does not resize to the bottom of the screen. It stays on the top of the now gone BottomNav

I tried observing on the visibility of the bottom bar and drawing a new one when the visibility changes. However the dismiss occurs after I draw the new snackBar, which dismisses it.

```
        bottomNavigationView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val newVis = bottomNavigationView.visibility
            if (bottomNavigationView.tag as Int != newVis) {
                bottomNavigationView.tag = bottomNavigationView.visibility
                if (p2NotificationSnackBar != null && p2NotificationSnackBar!!.isShown) {
                    Logger.d(TAG, "BottomNavigationBar visibility changed")

                    val snackBarTextView = p2NotificationSnackBar!!.view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
                    val snackBarText = snackBarTextView.text.toString()
                    p2NotificationSnackBar!!.dismiss()
                    p2NotificationCount = currentMessageCount
                    displayP2Notification(message = snackBarText, redrawSnackBar = true)
                }
            }
        }
```

Ideally I'd like the snackbar to move to the bottom without needing redraw. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only API that worked was the setY API that belongs to the View class. Get the view of the snackbar and call the setY value. It instantly moves to the new Y value

```
snackbar.view.setY = 0F
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a race condition where your visibility is altered after you draw the snackbar. Perhaps changing the order of events would be helpful. Or perhaps, drawing the snackbar at the bottom of the screen instead of above the bottom nav would achieve what you are after.

Also, you could have a true observer/observable situation vs this layout listener, that subscribes to the event of the visibility reaching your desired state and then redrawing the snackbar.

Hope that helps, I don't think there is a quick solution here.